# Intérprete de Python no reconoce librerias

Tags: python-3.7

Necesito instalar una librería en Python 3.7 , lo realizo mediante cmd con el comando pip.
La librería que necesito es openpyxl para poder trabajar con excel. 
El problema es que al querer importar la librería en mi código el intérprete me devuelve un error.
Pensé que se había instalado mal y repetí el proceso pero nada, me aseguré que este instalado yendo al directorio de Python C:\Phyton3.7\Lib\site-packages. Si ejecuto el import desde cmd no me devuelve mensaje de error, caso contrario cuando lo hago del intérprete:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habré omitido algun paso? Probé reinstalar el programa y bajar de nuevo las librerias pero no me dio resultado.

Answer (score 0):

reinstale python y funciona de 10.